# NSDateFormatter and default locale cause bug

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter, nslocale

Looks like `locale` setter has some magic, which forces the `dateFormatter` works properly

```
+(NSDate*)dateTimeFromJSONDateString:(NSString*)dateString{ //dateString i.e. 2013-11-19T12:47:38+04:00
    static NSDateFormatter *kDateFormatter;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        kDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//      kDateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ru_RU"];
        [kDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
    });
    NSLog(@"%@",  kDateFormatter.locale.localeIdentifier); // this one prints 'ru_RU' always either I set kDateFormatter.locale explicitly or not

    return [kDateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

so this method returns `nil` when 6th line is commented, otherwise it returns correct date.
Am I doing something wrong, or we have sdk bug here?

Comment: You need to set the formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX` when parsing such fixed format date strings.

Comment: @rmaddy can you please give me some link with more info?

Comment: Do a search on `NSDateFormatter` and `en_US_POSIX`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem solved by setting the formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX`. It is necessary while parsing fixed-format date strings because the format of the date strings is constant unlike device' locale.

The code should be like

```
+(NSDate*)dateTimeFromJSONDateString:(NSString*)dateString{
    static NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        _dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
        [_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
    });
    if (string)
        return [_dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
    else
        return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's documented or is a bug, but in iOS 7 (or XCode 5, not sure of the origin of the problem) you have to set the explicitly locale of NSDateFormatter before parsing date strings, or you get nil dates

Until XCode 5/iOS 7,  NSDateFormatter had as default the locale of the phone, and you didn't get a nil date

I found this problem mantaining old applications, that suddenly started returning nil dates

Comment: I'm using xcode5/ios7 in this particular situation, and yes, the default locale for dateformatter is current system locale. But as I said the function returns nil. I assume it is because my time format on the device is `am/pm`, which is not default time format for my current locale (russian). So when the current locale is used, dateformatter can't handle with my dateFormat `HH:mm:ss` which is actually 24-hour format. But when I explicitly set the RU locale (which has 24-hour time format by default), the dateformatter works properly. @rmaddy gave correct answer previously

Comment: if you compile with old xcode, it works

if you compule with xcode5, there is no default, you have to explicitly set it